# Are US Border Officials allowed to ask for my passwords from a legal perspective?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, legal

Can US Border Officials (e.g. Customs Officials at JFK Airport) legally require a non US citizen (whether a tourist, visa, or green card holder) for his or her passwords (phone, laptop, facebook, email, etc...)? Don't they need a warrant for that? Do different states have different rules?

Comment: Also related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22380/what-should-i-do-to-protect-data-when-going-across-the-us-border-with-a-computer/22399#22399

Comment: Also related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60363/what-exactly-can-us-immigration-search-or-ask-me-to-do-to-enter-the-us

Comment: No officer needs a warrant to *ask* for anything. The fourth amendment governs what they can *require,* but nothing stops them from requesting consent.

Comment: @phoog updated question with better terminology. Can they 'require'/'force' people to provide passwords or access to devices or accounts?

Comment: @pnuts I would rather stand up for my rights (if only I knew them). Plus, I would also prefer not to give away my company data (for no reasons) and keep my job...

Comment: Well, it won't be (legally) different by state. The border is a federal function.

Comment: @Gevorg Learn this, once and for all: except for permanent residents, foreigners have **no rights** whatsoever at the border (although visa holders can appeal an entry refusal to an immigration judge). Although it is "optional" to provide the CBP with your social media info, the slightest provocation (i.e. attempt to "stand up for your rights") can lead to you being sent back and possibly even blacklisted.